# Long Query Times

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 23.5 million rows and 20 columns.  I updated the table to set one of the columns to `null`.  This query took an hour to complete.  Granted, I don't have an amazingly fast database server, but is this update time normal?  I didn't have an index on this table when I ran the update.  How much would that have helped?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not shocked at that timeframe if you were updating all the rows.

Look into indexing your table (if it isn't already) to help your speed.

Comment: @limney indexing doesn't help as i said in my answer.

Comment: @Limey indexing will make insert/updates even slower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering it updated ALL rows, an index wouldn't have helped any.

Were there reads going on at the same time?  Updates cause row level locking, even if brief, could cause a lot of traffic and waiting in the transaction log.

Comment: Nothing else was going on in the db.

Comment: nope, if you don't have a 'WHERE', it just does a full table scan/update so that's just what it takes to update 23 million records

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly an acceptable time for your database server's number of rows, especially since you said it is not that fast. If you had an index it wouldn't have helped. Indexes are used to help the database server find specific records faster.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was probably a pretty normal time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating and setting the column to null, you can drop the column and re-add it as nullable. In my experience, this is many times faster than updating and setting each row to have null in that field.